# Symfony 4 doctrine, is there a way for execute the command "doctrine:migrations:diff" without an error if there are no changes detected?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

For Symfony 4 in a CI context, I need create a (bash) script to update my application.

In this script, I use the command `./bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`, but when I haven't added/modified any Entity, this command returns an error:

[image: error snippet]

(the bash code return is 1)

I'm looking for a proper way to execute this command without an error if there aren't any changes detected in mapping information. (no exception / code return 0 ).

The reason is I want stop all the script if I get somewhere a code return 1

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new command that internally calls `doctrine:migrations:diff`, and that catches `Doctrine\Migrations\Generator\Exception\NoChangesDetected`.

Here Is explained how you can create such a command

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html